# acf search by custom field rest api

Tags: wordpress

I've added a custom field `"acf": { "id": "2"}` for the default Categories taxonomy in posts.

How can I search the `acf: id` in rest api?

I've tried the following but doesn't work:
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/taxo-type?_fields=acf.id=18

I've already check the Show in REST API option in ACF ui.

```
{
    "id": 18,
    "count": 0,
    "description": "",
    "link": "http://localhost/wordpress/taxo-type/taxo-again/",
    "name": "taxo again",
    "slug": "taxo-again",
    "taxonomy": "taxo-type",
    "parent": 0,
    "meta": [],
    "acf": {
        "id": "2"
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/taxo-type/18"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/taxo-type"
            }
        ],
        "about": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies/taxo-type"
            }
        ],
        "wp:post_type": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?taxo-type=18"
            }
        ],
        "curies": [
            {
                "name": "wp",
                "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```